# Android sign in asking repeatedly

Tags: android, google-play-games, android-googleapiclient

I am trying to use GoogleApiClient and when I tried to sign in the application instead of sign in it repeatedly asking the choose the account.I am not able figure it out the solution.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B60egT7coPSETTJhTHZjOC1IdGs/view?usp=sharing this link shows the behaviour of the application

this is the code which i used

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                      .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
                      .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually arise when the methods that are overriden by the extended class ***BaseGameActivity*** are not called in the ***onActivityResult***. Please make sure that your code is called in the onActivityResult of the calling activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 ....
 put all your methods/code here
}
```

Take a look at the code for the [BaseGameActivity](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameActivity.java), the GameHelper calls the onActivityResult passing all the necessary parameters along with the intent.

Also try these:

- Clear your cookies
- Clear your cache
- Make sure your system time is correct.